# Setting the component using setTabComponent

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jtabbedpane

if I set a JButton as the tabComponent using

```
tabbedPane.setTabComponent(new JButton("test"));
```

The button covers a part of the tab while I can still see background of the tab.
But my requirement is to set this Button component on the tab completely as if the button should cover the whole tab as if there should be no access to that tab.

Comment: Could you show us what happens and what you want to happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might try using this method:

```
UIManager.put ( "TabbedPane.tabInsets", new Insets ( 0, 0, 0, 0 ) );
```

to remove tab insets and this one:

```
UIManager.put ( "TabbedPane.selectedTabPadInsets", new Insets ( 0, 0, 0, 0 ) );
```

to remove selected tab additional insets.

There is also a few other options that are **usually** taken from UI defaults:

```
    highlight = UIManager.getColor("TabbedPane.light");
    lightHighlight = UIManager.getColor("TabbedPane.highlight");
    shadow = UIManager.getColor("TabbedPane.shadow");
    darkShadow = UIManager.getColor("TabbedPane.darkShadow");
    focus = UIManager.getColor("TabbedPane.focus");
    selectedColor = UIManager.getColor("TabbedPane.selected");
    textIconGap = UIManager.getInt("TabbedPane.textIconGap");
    tabInsets = UIManager.getInsets("TabbedPane.tabInsets");
    selectedTabPadInsets = UIManager.getInsets("TabbedPane.selectedTabPadInsets");
    tabAreaInsets = UIManager.getInsets("TabbedPane.tabAreaInsets");
    tabsOverlapBorder = UIManager.getBoolean("TabbedPane.tabsOverlapBorder");
    contentBorderInsets = UIManager.getInsets("TabbedPane.contentBorderInsets");
    tabRunOverlay = UIManager.getInt("TabbedPane.tabRunOverlay");
    tabsOpaque = UIManager.getBoolean("TabbedPane.tabsOpaque");
    contentOpaque = UIManager.getBoolean("TabbedPane.contentOpaque");
    opaque = UIManager.get("TabbedPane.opaque");
```

You might want to modify some of them aswell to achieve what you need...

Comment: Even if i try to set the Insets through UI Manager, it is not reflecting on the tabs.

Comment: That depends on the UI you are using. In some case it might not have any effect. By the way, when do you set those properties - before or after LaF is set?

Comment: Actually my requirement is I want to set a Button on the tab which in turn the Button should look like a tab so that that particular tab will have a different style.

Comment: To change tabs styling properly you should replace tabbed pane UI with your own and modify it. That will be the best way.